# Problems with two threads accessing a frequently updated Arraylist

Tags: java, multithreading, data-structures, iterator, arraylist

I have ArrayLists that store many objects, and objects are frequently added and removed from the ArrayLists. One thread operates on the data structures and updates the ArrayList's objects every 20ms or so. Another thread traverses the ArrayLists and uses their elements to paint the objects (also every 20-30ms).

If the ArrayLists are traversed using a for loop, IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions abound. If the ArrayLists are traversed using iterators, ConcurrentModificationExceptions abound. Synchronizing the ArrayLists like so:

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
synchronized(list) {
//use iterator for traversals
}
```

Throws no exceptions but has a substantial performance drain. Is there a way to traverse these ArrayLists without exceptions being throw, and without a performance drain?

THANKS!

Comment: Yes, you have threading bugs and you're lucky to be getting the exceptions that you are.  What kind of modifications does the first thread do?  Certain paradigms are easier to make thread-safe than others.  If the list is small, you could consider `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

Comment: I used the CopyOnWriteArrayList, seems to be working well. However when I traverse the list using an iterator, it a call to remove(object) throws a UnsupportedOperationException. A for loop runs through it without a problem.

Comment: if you want to remove objects from the CopyOnWriteArrayList determined during traversal, save them all up in a separate collection and call removeAll() when you are done.

Comment: I'm doubtful that you *need* to make structural modifications to your list in your "painting" code.  You need to decouple your two threads further or else you will be stuck with poor performance due to synchronization between threads.  If you post a simplified version of your code, maybe people can help you reorganize it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good approach to this problem is to make threads work on different copies of the list. However, `CopyOnWriteArrayList` doesn't fit here well, since it creates a copy at every modification, but in your case it would be better to create copies less frequent.

So, you can implement it manually: the first thread creates a copy of the updated list and publishes it via the `volatile` variable, the second thread works with this copy (I assume that the first thread modifies only list, not objects in it):

```
private volatile List publicList;

// Thread A
List originalList = ...;
while (true) {
    modifyList(originalList); // Modify list
    publicList = new ArrayList(originalList); // Pusblish a copy
}

// Thread B
while (true) {
    for (Object o: publicList) { // Iterate over a published copy
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 a decent caching strategy which is much courser grained than the `CopyOnWriteArrayList`. The Thread which is changing the array works on the "working" copy and periodically updates a "snapshot" copy. The Thread which is simply rendering the list contents works on a "snapshot" copy.

Comment: I switched yours to best answer. CopyOnWriteArrayLists are a performance hog.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the `Iterator` and using a [**CopyOnWriteArrayList**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)? It is guaranteed not to throw `ConcurrentModificationException`s.

From the Oracle javadocs (emphasis added):

> A thread-safe variant of ArrayList in
>   which all mutative operations (add,
>   set, and so on) are implemented by
>   making a fresh copy of the underlying
>   array.
>
> This is ordinarily too costly, **but may
>   be more efficient than alternatives
>   when traversal operations vastly
>   outnumber mutations, and is useful
>   when you cannot or don't want to
>   synchronize traversals**, yet need to
>   preclude interference among concurrent
>   threads. The "snapshot" style iterator
>   method uses a reference to the state
>   of the array at the point that the
>   iterator was created. This array never
>   changes during the lifetime of the
>   iterator, so interference is
>   impossible and **the iterator is
>   guaranteed not to throw
>   ConcurrentModificationException**. The
>   iterator will not reflect additions,
>   removals, or changes to the list since
>   the iterator was created.
>   Element-changing operations on
>   iterators themselves (remove, set, and
>   add) are not supported. These methods
>   throw UnsupportedOperationException.

Answer (score 2):

What about copying the ArrayList into a new variable prior to iterating over it? That way you only need to synchronize the copy block and not the entire iteration of the list.

Answer (score 1):

The [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) class was created to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CopyOnWriteArrayList which doesn't get a ConcurrentModificationException nor does it need to be synchronized, or you can do something like.

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());

List copy;
// lock the list for the minimal amount of time.
synchronized(list) {
    copy = new ArrayList(list);
}
// use the copy of the array list.
```

BTW CopyOnWriteArrayList would look like

```
List list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList();

// use the list.
```

Answer (score 1):

Although CopyOnWriteArrayList provides maximum performance for readers, there are writer performance issues if writes are frequent.

If your access pattern is only through the iterator and you don't do any random access, then using a queue may be a better choice, as you can use things like ConcurrentLinkedQueue. See for example [JAVA: Concurrency control for access to list in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943223/java-concurrency-control-for-access-to-list-in-java/3944549#3944549).